# Problems with nested form Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

I am trying to save in 2 tables in the same time, using nested form. I do not know why this is not happening. Rails error says "1 error prohibited this person from being saved:" Why the Legal Person is not getting the Person_id?

Models

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :legal_person, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :legal_person
end


class LegalPerson < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :person
end
```

Controller

```
class PeopleController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_person, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /people
  # GET /people.json
  def index
    @people = Person.all
  end

  # GET /people/1
  # GET /people/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /people/new
  def new
    @person = Person.new
    @person.build_legal_person
  end

  # GET /people/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /people
  # POST /people.json
  def create
    @person = Person.new(person_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @person.save
        format.html { redirect_to @person, notice: 'Person was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @person }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @person.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /people/1
  # PATCH/PUT /people/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @person.update(person_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @person, notice: 'Person was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @person }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @person.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /people/1
  # DELETE /people/1.json
  def destroy
    @person.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to people_url, notice: 'Person was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_person
      @person = Person.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def person_params
      #params.require(:person).permit(:nome, :tipopessoa, :telefonefixo, :telefonecelular)
      params.require(:person).permit(:nome, :tipopessoa, :telefonefixo, :telefonecelular,
                                     legal_person_attributes: LegalPerson.attribute_names.map(&:to_sym))
                                     #legal_person_attributes: [:id, :cnpj, :nomefantasia, :person_id])
    end
end
```

Error

```
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"pAAOYapSgnF8H6O2cJMpHSN6POBwAzycy00Tij5TKFDv+8d+EErtdQGKuRbay4IxKrUQjXVPq5MblVgjv5Fa5g==", "person"=>{"nome"=>"qweqw", "tipopessoa"=>"wqeqweq", "telefonefixo"=>"qweqe", "telefonecelular"=>"qweqw", "legal_person_attributes"=>{"cnpj"=>"qweqw", "nomefantasia"=>"wqewe"}}, "commit"=>"Criar Person"}
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
```

Answer (score 0):

use attribute name `[:cnpj, :nomefantasia]` instead of

```
LegalPerson.attribute_names.map(&:to_sym)
```